# Getting a random choice from an array

Tags: python-3.x

I tried using the random.choice command and it seems to not work.
The Wolf has already been assigned to mob

```
class Wolf(Character):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(name="wolf",hp=7,atk=6,df=4,inventory={},spells= 
{"bite": randint(3,6)},exp=8)

c = random.choice(mob.spells)            
spower = mob.spells[c]          
ad = mob.atk / hero.df          
damage = ad * spower          
damage = int(round(damage))
```

Comment: Random choice gives you an *element*, not its index.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I find the index randomly?

Comment: @Waterbin I added the code you need at the end of my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`random.choice` wont work because you are passing a dictionary and it expects something that can be indexed using integer indices. Choosing randomly from a dictionary could work if the keys are integers.

```python
d = {'a': 10, 'b': 20}
random.choice(d)
```

The above code will fail, but this will work:

```python
d = {1: 10, 0: 20}
random.choice(d)
```

Its not magic, it works because the code in `random.choice` chooses a random integer between `0` and `len(obj)` and return the object at that index. The code below will never work:

```python
d = {-1: 10, 2: 20}
random.choice(d)
```

And this will work sometimes:

```python
d = {'a': 10, 0: 20}
random.choice(d)
```

It doesnt make any sense to find a *random index* in a dictionary.

For **getting a random key in a dictionary** do this:

```python
d = {'a': 10, -1: 20, 90: -90}
random_key = random.choice(list(d))
```

In your case, the code will be:

```python
c = random.choice(list(mob.spells))
```

Comment: This was really helpful and now I actually know what I did wrong after hours of trying to figure it out. I learnt something here, thank you for your help

Comment: No problem, anytime, bro!